# Android 2.3 and ISO 15693

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, nexus-s, iso-15693

I want to know if Android 2.3 Gingerbread and the Nexus S phone supports reading/writing ISO 15693 RFID chips? As of now, I know it can READ ISO 14443...

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm maybe too late, but I could read some RFID 15693 with my Nexus S at work. I don't try to read data in it, I only need to read the unique identifier for my project.

Best regards

Comment: Hey Hrk, it's never too late. So did you read it with android's own library (android.nfc) or did you have to use some hack to do it?

Comment: As we speak at the phone, it's with the official android.nfc API ! Have a look at the bottom of this page : http://www.nfc-world.com/en/about/ I think the Nexus S reader is based on NFC IP-2. But I don't know for further android device.

Comment: I can confirm that too; I was able to read a contactless ski pass with one of the RFID info apps that are available in the market with an unmodified Nexus S on 2.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Mifare is based on ISO/IEC 14443, not on ISO/IEC 15693
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIFARE

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with this kind of chip, you have to use the following API from android :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html

The NfcV API was added in API level 10, corresponding as this page says to Android 2.3.3.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

If you are using Android 2.3 GINGERBREAD, you have to upgrade your phone to at least Android 2.3.3 GINGERBREAD_MR1. Once you have done so, you'll be able to use the following methods from the api :

```
Tag tag = ...;
nfc = NfcV.get(tag);
nfc.connect();
byte[] read = nfc.transceive(new byte[]{0x00, 0x20, 0x05});
nfc.close();
```

In this example, the phone will send 0x00, 0x20, 0x005 corresponding to the command to read block 5 from the card.

You can find the different avaliable commands and the answer the card will give in each case by googling "ISO/IEC FCD 15693 3" and taking the first link (yeah "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links." --')